# What's the cheapest sim cards with mobile internet available for Tourists in Paris?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, paris

I'm traveling to Paris for 5 days and I think the best way to communicate with French friends is if I have a local number and a mobile internet as well. And also, how much is it? and how much data can I get from it?

Thank you!